# Count the number of rows inserted in a table per second

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, scripting

I want to be able to count number of rows inserted in a table per second using SQL database. The count has to be for all the rows in the table. Sometimes there could be 100 rows and others 10 etc so this is just for stats. I managed to count rows per day but need more details. Any advise or any scripts would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You really should provide a data sample and the SQL code you're working with to get better answers. This is too vague of a question to answer as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you truncate the datetime column to the second.
Then you can aggregate on it, to get totals per second.

For example:

```
SELECT
CAST(dt AS DATE) as [Date],
MIN(Total) as MinRecordsPerSec,
MAX(Total) as MaxRecordsPerSec,
AVG(Total) as AverageRecordsPerSec
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(19), YourDatetimeColumn, 120), 120) as dt, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY CONVERT(char(19), YourDatetimeColumn, 120)
) q
GROUP BY CAST(dt AS DATE)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on language you are using, the way to do this would be to fetch your DB and change date column to timestamp, then group them by each stamp as you would know each timestamp is per second.

OR

Alternatively, you can store timestamps in DB instead of actual date the it will be easy to query from DB.

OR

Use this function 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' in mysql to get timestamp of column then you can do whatever and whichever comparison you want to do on it 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp
Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I m only using sql management studio for this and SQL so i just want to execute the script on the sql studio

Comment: Ok then use 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' on column and then group them, read this 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp